# Prevent python from converting \x41 to A

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding

In my code I receive a bytearray with the value 0x41 as b'\x41'. Printing this value gives b'A'. How can I print it in such a way that i get the result b'\x41'. (Python 3.7)

Testcode:

```
print("b'\x41'")
```

Comment: I voted to close before adding the Python tag. Hopefully someone else can hammer this question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Unfortunately, if you don't like the default display, you have to generate it yourself:

```
>>> b = b'\x41\x42\x43'
>>> print(b)
b'ABC'
>>> print("b'" + ''.join(f'\\x{c:02x}' for c in b) + "'")
b'\x41\x42\x43'
```